# I don't have firefox and I'm getting firefox updates?

Tags: firefox, update-manager

I don't have firefox and I'm getting firefox updates in the "Software Updater" how can I fix this or disabled this update because I don't want update files on my computer that will do no good.

Comment: Have you removed Firefox since you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you have ice weasel?

Comment: The thing is I use Google Chrome, it's rarely I go to a different browser but, I don't have ice weasel, and I uninstall firefox like a month ago but I installed Ubuntu almost a 4 months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have firefox installed, and haven't uninstalled it, then you'll still receive updates.

To start, open a terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Your prompt should look something like this (names probably won't match:

```
user@desktop:~$
```

Then, you should run the commands below in order. When it asks for a password, enter *YOUR* password. Nothing will appear as you type your password. That is intended and normal behaviour.

### To Uninstall:

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox
```

### To Update the List of Software Updates:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

### To Upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it and I hope I don't get those firefox updates.